# joint state publisher and robot state publisher

Tags: joint-state-publisher, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the difference between `joint_state_publisher` and `robot_state_publisher`?
I understand that I get robot state publisher from the URDF but the joint state?  What if i want real data not fake?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275079/joint-state-publisher-and-robot-state-publisher/) by [marawy_alsakaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/31902/marawy_alsakaf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-11-06

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-11-06**:
What do you mean

> if i want real data not fake

?

**Comment by [marawy_alsakaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/31902/marawy_alsakaf/) on 2017-11-06**:
i mean if i want joint state from real robot not for simulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [`robot_state_publisher` wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher):

> `robot_state_publisher` uses the URDF specified by the parameter `robot_description` and the joint positions from the topic `joint_states` to calculate the forward kinematics of the robot and publish the results via [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf).

From the [`joint_state_publisher` wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher):

> This package publishes `sensor_msgs/JointState` messages for a robot. The package reads the `robot_description` parameter, finds all of the non-fixed joints and publishes a `JointState` message with all those joints defined.
>
> Can be used in conjunction with the `robot_state_publisher` node to also publish transforms for all joint states.

Basically, the `robot_state_publisher` publishes the `tf` transforms of your robot based on its URDF file. You can also publish the joint states using the `joint_state_publisher` or do it yourself. Either way, the `robot_state_publisher` uses this information to calculate the forward kinematics of your robot.

---

**Update:**

If you want to publish your own `sensor_msgs/JointState` messages then take a look at [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher#Publishing_the_State).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 19

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marawy_alsakaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/31902/marawy_alsakaf/) on 2017-11-06**:
ok
so i should now publish my jointstate (as in the tutorial)
but for robot state i did not need to write any node, i called the robot state publisher in my launch file with URDF and it worked
am i right ?

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-21**:
I have used both the joint_state_publisher and robot_state_publisher in my demo_gazebo.launch file shown [here](https://github.com/matthewmarkey44/arm/blob/master/src/t800/launch/demo_gazebo.launch)...

I am publishing to joint_states from multiple sources, but I am unsure of how to rectify the situation. The current Gazebo output can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3ppf2po_uU).

With my rostopic info joint_states:

```
homefolder@ubuntu:~$ rostopic info joint_states
Type: sensor_msgs/JointState

Publishers: 
 * /joint_state_publisher (http://ubuntu:41201/)
 * /gazebo (http://ubuntu:34151/)

Subscribers: 
 * /move_group (http://ubuntu:39291/)
 * /joint_state_publisher (http://ubuntu:41201/)
```

I am really lost on what I am doing wrong.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-05-21**:
@matthewmarkey  you should ask a new question. Comments aren't the place to ask a new question

**Comment by [matthewmarkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/54103/matthewmarkey/) on 2020-05-21**:
Ok, I have done this. Do you have a minute to give some advice? @jayess

[352941](https://answers.ros.org/question/352941/what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-robot_state_publisher-and-joint_state_publisher/)

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2021-04-04**:
Is it correct then that if the URDF does not define any joints that can move then one doesn't ever need to launch launch_state_publisher?